# How Do I delete properties from nested foreach JObject?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm converting custom model into JObject and I want delete properties which are null in JObject. How can loop Jobject?

```
var serData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customModel);
            JObject jsonData = JObject.Parse(serData);

foreach (var opt in jsonData["parameters"])
            {
                if (((JProperty)opt).Name.ToString() == "constraints")
                {
                    //foreach (var cons in opt["constraints"])
                    foreach (var cons in ((JProperty)opt)["constraints"])
                    {
                        if (((JProperty)cons).Name.ToString() == "price_constraints")
                        {
                            foreach (var price in cons["price_constraints"])
                            {
                                if(price["price_level_3"] == null){
                                    //delete;
                                }    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


{
    "parameters":{
        "constraints": {
          "minimum": 5,
          "minimum": 7
          "price_constraints": {
            "price_level_1": {
              "price": 0.0,
            },
            "price_level_2": {
              "price": 55.0,
            },
            "price_level_3": null,
            "price_level_4": null,    
          }             
        }
    }
}
```

I'm converting custom model into JObject and I want delete properties which are null in JObject. How can loop JObject?

Comment: [`JObject.Remove`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Remove.htm)

Comment: After remove I'm getting "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

Comment: Yeah, you can't modify a collection that you're iterating through with `foreach`

Comment: I'm adding removed properties in List<JProperty> toRemove = new List<JProperty>();  for (int i=0; i< toRemove.Count() ; i++)
            {
                if (jsonData["parameters"]["constraints"]["price_constraints"].Contains(toRemove[i]))
                {
                    jsonData["parameters"]["constraints"]["price_constraints"][toRemove[i]].Remove();

                }
            }

Comment: here how can I remove?